# Atomicity guaranteed on "lock" methods in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, mutex, semaphore, atomic

We know that the following kernel methods in Linux allow us to apply various locking mechanisms on shared data. But, does Linux guarantee atomicity on the methods themselves? With the exception to methods related to normal and reader-writer spin locks, which cannot sleep, wouldn't it be catastrophic if a thread of execution is preempted while it has partially executed any of the other methods mentioned below?

**Spin Lock Methods**

```
spin_lock();
spin_lock_irq();
spin_lock_irqsave();
spin_unlock();
spin_unlock_irq();
spin_unlock_irqrestore();
spin_lock_init();
spin_trylock();
spin_is_locked();
```

**Reader-Writer Spin Lock Methods**

```
read_lock();
read_lock_irq(); 
read_lock_irqsave(); 
read_unlock();
read_unlock_irq();
read_unlock_ irqrestore(); 
write_lock();
write_lock_irq();
write_lock_irqsave(); 
write_unlock();
write_unlock_irq(); 
write_unlock_irqrestore();
write_trylock();
rwlock_init();
```

**Semaphore Methods**

```
sema_init();
init_MUTEX(); 
init_MUTEX_LOCKED();
down_interruptible(); 
down();
down_trylock(); 
up();
```

**Reader-Writer Semaphore Methods**

```
init_rwsem();
down_read();
up_read();
down_write();
up_write();
down_read_trylock();
down_write_trylock();
downgrade_write();
```

**Mutex Methods**

```
mutex_lock();
mutex_unlock();
mutex_trylock();
mutex_is_locked();
```

**Completion Variable Methods**

```
init_completion();
wait_for_completion();
complete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these functions were not atomic with respect to the lock itself, they would not work at all. And last time I looked, my Linux did work.

Most of these functions indeed disable preemption while doing their stuff.

Comment: This is what I wished to see written. :)

Answer (score 0):

Semaphore, Reader-writer semeaphores would automatically disable kernel preemption in SMP systems.